# Where to load data for fragments?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm a bit confused as to where to load the data that my fragment needs. I've got my data stored in Parse.com and I'm capable of reading it. However I'm confused as to where to do that in order to minimize passing data around. What I've got is the following:

A TakeActivity that displays a ListFragment:

```
public class TakeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ShiftsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

Then I've got a ShiftsFragment which displays details about the Shifts:

```
public class ShiftsFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ParseQuery<Shift> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Shift.class);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Shift>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Shift> shifts, ParseException e) {
                ShiftAdapter adapter = new ShiftAdapter(getActivity(), shifts);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to make it so that when you click on a shift in the listview it takes you to the details page. I've tried to do it like they say in: [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

However I run into the problem that my ShiftDetailFragment doesn't have the data that ShiftsFragment does. I also read somewhere that you shouldn't be passing live ParseObjects around.

How do I make my data available to both fragments?

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as we don't know what your "data" consists of - it also assumes other Android developers know anything about parse.com. The bottom line is (as explained in the link you posted) no Fragment should know about the existence of any other Fragment - the Activity which contols the Fragments should be used as a central point and all communications performed through the Activity. In short, have your Activity maintain the data you need and simply pass events etc via a 'callbacks' interface allowing the Activity to pass what it needs to on to the other Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your List in your Activity and write an Interface for the Fragments to access or update the list.

Something along the lines of:

---

```
public Interface ShiftListInterface {
    public List<Shift> getShiftList();
    public void setShiftList(List<Shift> shiftList);
    public Shift getShift(int shiftIndex);
    public void updateShift(int shiftIndex, Shift shift);
}
```

---

```
public class TakeActivity
            extends ActionBarActivity
            implements ShiftListInterface {

    // hold your dataset in your Activity
    private List<Shift> shiftList;


    // load your dataset here
    private void loadShifts() {
        ParseQuery<Shift> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Shift.class);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Shift>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Shift> shifts, ParseException e) {
                shiftList = shifts;
            }
        });
    }

    // implement methods from the interface to allow access to the list
    @Override
    public List<Shift) getShiftList() {
        return shiftList;
    }

    @Override
    public void setShiftList(List<Shift> shiftList) {
        this.shiftList = shiftList;
    }

    @Override
    public Shift getShift(int shiftindex) {
        return shiftList.get(shidtIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateShift(int shiftIndex, Shift shift) {
        shiftList.set(shiftIndex, shift);
    }

    ...
}
```

---

```
public class ShiftsFragment extends ListFragment {

    // hold a reference to the interface defined
    private ShiftListInterface shiftListInterface;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // make sure the parent activity implements your interface
        try
        {
            shiftListInterface = (ShiftListInterface) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Parent Activity doesn't implement ShiftListInterface");
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ShiftListInterface");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ShiftAdapter adapter = new ShiftAdapter(getActivity(),
                                    shiftListInterface.getShiftList());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    ...
}
```

---

```
public DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ShiftListInterface shiftListInterface;
    private int shiftIndex;
    private Shift shift;

    public DetailsFragment(int shiftIndex) {
        // pass in the index of the Shift you want to display
        this.shiftIndex = shiftIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            shiftListInterface = (ShiftListInterface) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Parent Activity doesn't implement ShiftListInterface");
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ShiftListInterface");
        }
        // after you ensure the interface exists you can grab the Shift
        this.shift = shiftListInterface.getShiftList().get(shiftIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shift_details,
                                     container, false);
        // populate your view using this.shift
        return view;
    }

    ...
}
```

You will just have to be careful to not pass a null List to your fragments and to notify them of changes when your request comes back and you parse it to get your list. I'll leave that part to you as I don't know how/when you are loading/handling your Fragments.